# Python, tictactoe, syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new with Python.  I found this website TheHelloWorldProgram.com that teaching me how to write a tictactoe game that very easy to understand but I ran into some problem.  I keep getting this syntax error message "invalid syntax" and it pointed to player = False.  it highlighted 'player'.  Why?  I couldn't figured it out.  Thanks for the help.  Below you will see the code of the game, please excuse the #comments.  They are for myself:

```
#importing randint from the random module
from random import randint

#create a list of play options
1 = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

#assign a random play to the computer
computer = t[randint(0,2)]

#set player to False
player = False

while player == False:
    #set player to True
    player = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?")

#if player = computer, it is a Tie!
    if player == computer:
        print("Tie!")

#else if player = ROCK 
    elif player == "Rock":
        #computer = paper
        if computer == "Paper":
            #player lost, paper beats rock
            print("You lose!", computer, "covers", player)
        else:
            #player win, rock beats scissors
            print("You win!", player, "smashes", computer)

#else if player = PAPER
    elif player == "Paper":
        #if computer = scissors
        if computer == "Scissors":
            #player lost, scissors beats paper
            print("You lose!", computer, "cut", player)
        else:
            #player win, paper beats rock
            print("You win!", player, "covers", computer)

#else if player = SCISSORS
    elif player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("You lose!", computer, "smashes", player)
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "cut", computer)
    else:
        print("That's not a valid play.  Check your spelling!"

    #player was set to True, but we want it to be False so the loop continues
    player = False
    computer = t[randint(0,2)]
```

Comment: `print("That's not a valid play.  Check your spelling!"` `<--` a missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: Is that a `1` in the 5th line, Column 1? (Counting blank and comment lines.)

Comment: Thank you Jim and Wick.  You hit the nail right on the head.  Most grateful.  that 1 meant to be variable t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1 = ['rock',etc] should be t = 
for reference python (and I think most languages) don't accept # as variable names
you could do t1, t_1, t, one, but not 1t, 1_t,.  So numbers and variables that start with numbers. as @Wickramaranga pointed out.

and as @Jim pointed out close your print statements. A good place to check with python errors is statements before the statement the error points to. So for example,

```
print("That's not a valid play.  Check your spelling!"

#player was set to True, but we want it to be False so the loop continues
player = False
```

Your error points to player = False, because when the python interpreter was executing the

```
print("That's not a valid play.  Check your spelling!"
```

It didn't see the ending ')'.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I made several mistakes there.
1 should be t and the missing ).  You gents and ladies are awesome.  Thank you much.